# Please help me understand a Figure in Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", Sec 1.5.1 Minimizing the misclassification rate

Tags: probability, classification, joint-distribution, decision-theory

The figure is Figure 1.24 on page 40 of Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", Sec 1.5.1 Minimizing the misclassification rate:

[image]

I don't understand this figure, starting from "Errors arise from the blue, green, and red regions, ..." For example, why does the red region represent points from $\mathcal{C}_2$? If this is because $p(x,\mathcal{C}_2)$ is greater than $p(x,\mathcal{C}_1)$ there, points $x<x_0$ are from $\mathcal{C}_1$ so the classification is correct. Why is it still green which means error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the understanding of the notation of joint probability distribution $p(x,\mathcal C_k)$. This joint probability distribution comes from ground-truth, perhaps a long-term collection of X-ray images and confirmed clinic diagnoses of whether the patients truly have cancer. So, $\mathcal C_k$ represents the truth; God defines that, while $\mathcal R_k$ represents the efforts of how we human being tries to make decision. The sum of red and green is the first integral of equation (1.78) $$\int_{\mathcal R_1}p(x,\mathcal C_2)dx.$$
The $\mathcal C_2$ in the integrand means that the sample $x$ is actually from class $\mathcal C_2$, as ground truth, but the integral bound $\mathcal R_1$ means that we human being thinks $x$ belongs to $\mathcal R_1$, or mistakenly assigned to class $\mathcal C_1$.